# Implement Hangout Chat

Tags: android

I need to implement a custom App to send and receive message (through hangout chat) using google account, I need use a hangout chat, but I was reviewing Google+ Hangouts API, but presents a message (Important: The Google+ API for Hangouts is no longer supported. Apps will continue to function until April 25, 2017 https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/).

I want to know if is possible implement the App (It is required use a Hangout chat), if the answer is positive, can anyone give a link where I can get steps about how to implement the chat.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Will this help you: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/sample-apps ? You can check the source code of sample apps. And maybe this: https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java I'm not 100% sure what are you trying to do

Comment: @Uata Thanks I will to review.

Answer (score 1):

Google Hangouts chat does not have a native API.

Consider using a third party reverse-engineered variation, such as https://github.com/tdryer/hangups

The hangoutsbot project (https://github.com/hangoutsbot/hangoutsbot) uses the third-party API I mentioned above, and provides a platform for you to develop your own plugins to interact with chats. You can develop an HTTP API as a plugin, or use the pre-existing API plugin